# Find Vertices of a Hanged Rectangle

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a rectangle hanged by a red thread and we want coordinates of all vertices. The rectangle can rotate around its center freely(I mean $J$ coordinate is constant but vertices are not), So I'm not looking for a solution for this specific problem(This image is only an example), **I'm looking for a general solution** which will give us coordinates of vertices (order of them doesn't matter) no matter what the angle is.

[image]

The only angle we got is the angle **between the thread and the center of rectangle's height** ($JL$ line I mean). We know diagonal ($2.7$) and the line which connects center of rectangle to middle of its height ($2.16$)

Note: $J$ Coordinates are $(0, 0)$

Comment: Apply a rotation matrix to the vertices of the "upright" rectangle (angle = 0).

Comment: @Aretino Sorry I'm not very familiar with this stuff, Can you explain it?

Comment: Rotating $(x,y)$ by $\varphi$ around the origin yields $(x',y')$, where $$\begin{cases}x' = x \cos(\varphi) - y \sin(\varphi) \\ y' = x \sin(\varphi) + y \cos(\varphi)\end{cases}$$See the Wikipedia article on [Rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions) for details and description.

Comment: Another option would be to form vector $\vec{v} = \overline{JL} = \left(\frac{4.32}{2} \sin(\varphi), \frac{4.32}{2} \cos(\varphi)\right)$, and another vector (with F near where $4.32$ is in the figure), $\vec{u} = \overline{JF} = \left(-\frac{3.23}{2}\cos(\varphi), \frac{3.23}\sin{\varphi}\right)$, and vector for $J$, $\vec{c}=(0,0)$. Then, the points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are at $\vec{c}+\vec{u}+\vec{v}$, $\vec{c}-\vec{u}+\vec{v}$, $\vec{c}+\vec{u}-\vec{v}$, and $\vec{c}-\vec{u}-\vec{v}$, respectively. If $L$ and $F$ are at the middle of their edges, this works for parallelograms, too.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks I've tested first formula and it works but do you know how can I calculate it if $J$ is not $(0, 0)$ ?

Comment: @omidh: I did. All that changes in the latter option if $J$ is not at origin, is $\vec{c}$. (If the shape were a parallelogram and not a rectangle, then $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ would change, pointing from the center of the parallelogram to the midpoints of their respective sides.)